# Design thoughts required about concurrent processing

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

I have a series of calculations that need to be processed - the calculations and the order they run are all defined by the user on the UI.

If they just ran one after each other, it wouldn't be too hard. However, some of the calculations need to be processed concurrently and all calculations must have the ability to be individually paused at any time. I also need to be able to re-arrange orders or add new calculations to be processed at any time. So whatever I do must be flexible enough to handle this.

On the UI, imagine a listbox (a queue, if you like) of usercontrols - with each usercontrol displaying the name of the calculation and a pause button. And I can add calculations to this list at any time during processing.

**What is the best way to do this?**

Should I be running each calculation in its own thread? If so, how should I store the list of running processes? How will I pass the queue to the calculation processor? How will I be able to ensure that every time the queue changes (new ordering or new calculation) the calculation processor will be made aware of this?

My initial thoughts were to have:

- `CalcProcessor class`
- `CalcCalculation class`

In `CalcProcessor` have 2 `Lists` of `CalcCalculations`. One being the "queue" as shown on the UI (perhaps a pointer to it? Or some other way to ensure it updates live), and the other being the list of currently running calculations.

Somehow I need to get the `CalcCalculation` to be running in its own thread to process the calculation, and be able to handle any pause events. So I need some way to transmit the info of the Pause button being pressed in the UI to the `CalcProcessor` object, and then into the correct `CalcCalculation`.

**Edit in response to David Hope:**

Thanks for your reply.

1. Yes, there are n calculations but this could change at any time due to being able to add more calculations to process on the UI.
2. They do not need to share data in anyway. There will be a setting in the application to specify how many should run concurrently (ie. 10 at any given time, the first 10 in the queue for example - and when 1 finishes the next calculation in the queue will start processing).
3. The calculation will involve taking data from some data source - it could be a database or a file, and analysing it and performing some calculations on that data. When I say the calculation needs to be paused, I don't mean pausing the thread... I just mean (for example, as I haven't written this part of the application yet) if it is reading row by row from a database and doing some live calculations pausing at the completion of processing the current row... and continuing on when the pause button is unclicked on the UI - which could be done with something as primitive as a while(notPaused) loop providing I can get the Pause information from the UI into the thread.

Comment: Can you use C# 5.0? What exactly do you mean by “some of the calculations need to be processed concurrently”? What are the rules? Would it be okay if paused calculation was wasting a thread?

Comment: I'll be using 4.0, and the thread must stay alive because even though the calculation is paused it will periodically need to update a log file to show that the calculation is still active (albeit paused). By calculations running concurrently, I just mean that they need to be running at the same time - a calculation doesn't rely on any other calculation in any way, but due to time constraints they must be running at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

There are several questions here:

### How to synchronize the UI and the model?

I think you got this one backwards. Your model shouldn't have a “pointer” to the queue you're showing in the UI. Instead, the queue should be in your model and you should use databinding together with `INotifyPropertyChange` and `ObservableCollection` to show the queue on the UI. (At least that's how it's done in WPF.)

This way, you can manipulate your queue directly from your model, and it will automatically show on the UI.

### How to start and monitor calculations?

I think `Task`s are ideal for this. You can start a `Task` using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. Since it seems your `Task`s will take long to execute, you might consider using [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx). You can also use the `Task` to find out when is the calculation complete (or if it failed with an exception).

### How to pause running calculations?

You can use [`ManualReserEventSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx) for that. Normally, it would be set, but if you wanted to pause a running `Task`, you would `Reset()` it. The calculation will need to periodically call `Wait()` on that event. It's not possible to reasonably pause a running thread without cooperation from the calculation on that thread.

If you were using C# 5.0, a better approach would be to use something like [`PauseToken`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In Framework 4.5, the answer here is the Async API, which removes the need to manage threads. For details, look at [the async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) keywords.

From a broader perspective, a "CalcProcessor" class is a good idea, but I think the Task object will suffice to replace your "CalcCalculation" class. The Processor can simply have an Enumerable of Tasks. The Processor can expose methods for managing the queue, if needed, as well as returning information about its status. When your application finally reaches a state where it must have the results, you can use the AwaitAll method to block the CalcProcessor's thread until all of the tasks complete.

Without more information about the actual goal here, it's hard to give better advice.

Comment: “Async API” doesn't remove the need to manage threads. If you want CPU-bound calculations to happen in parallel, you still need to explicitly send it to another thread, usually using `Task.Run()`.

Comment: In general, you're better off letting the framework decide if it should live in another thread or not. You still need to manage the task execution, but you're operating at a higher, more abstract level, than individual threads.

Comment: But the framework doesn't really decide that, even if you use `await`. The rules deciding where will the code run are quite strict, the framework can't just decide it will run some code on another thread. And if you want parallel processing, you really should explicitly state that (like I said, using `Task.Run()`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to display results on UI and order changes back in to Processor. [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) and [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) patterns will help you to start, pause, cancel the calculations. These patterns have great answers to your questions in design way. Concurrency is still a problem, they do not answer multi-threading problems but they open an easier road to manage threads.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very applicable to me. I have a question though... presumably I would need a unique identifier in each CalcCalculation so that when the method is called there is some way to match it up with the correct object so the right calculation is paused? Is this right? Additionally... say CalcCalculation has a Run() method which starts the calculation in a new thread... I am unsure how I can pass the pause information into the running thread? It may be a simple question - I have done a bit with threading in the past but I cannot recall a time where I've had to pass information *IN*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you haven't broken the problem down far enough, which is the reason you are frustrated.

You need to start small and build up from there. You mention, but don't define your actual requirements, but they seem to be...

1. Need to be able to run ?N? calculations
2. Some need to be run concurrently (does this imply that they share data, if so how are you going to share the data)
3. Must be able to pause the calculation (don't use Thread.Suspend, as it potentially leaves a thread in an unstable state, particularly bad if you are sharing data), so you will need to build pause points into each calculation. Also need to consider how you are going to communicate the pause/unpause to the calculation

As far as methods, there are several to consider...

Threads are an obvious choice, but require careful tending too (starting, pausing, stopping, etc...)

You could also use BackGroundWorker or possibly Parallel.ForEach

BackGroundWorker contains the framework for cancelling the worker and providing progress (which can be useful).

My recommendation to start would be to go with BackGroundWorker, potentially subclass it to add the Pause/Resume functionality you need. Determine how you are going to manage data sharing (at least use lock to protect against simultaneous access).

You may find BackGroundWorker too restrictive and need to go with Threads, but I'm usually able to avoid it.

If you post more clear requirements, or samples of what you've tried and didn't work, I'll be happy to help more.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, I am editing my original post as my response was too long to put in here.

Answer (score 0):

For queue you can use heap data structure (priority queue). This will help prioritize yours tasks. Also you should use Thread Pool for effectively calculations. And try to split you tasks to little parts.